# How to disable/remove browser notification?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Using "medium" security setting in Tor browser, slows login to protonmail.
Notification bar opens with "A web page is slowing down your browser, What would you like to do?
Choices: "Stop It" or "Wait".
Clicking wait, just brings bar back in few seconds...annoying!
So, How to remove/disable this helpful annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

Protonmail, and many other sites, make heavy use of javascript, higher security levels disable [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).

Disabling JIT has a measureable impact on javascripts performance, as such the Protonmail tab appears to be locking-up and so Tor Browser is prompting you to decide if you want to wait for it fo finish processing or stop it.

The only solution would be to set the security slider to Low while using Protonmail to allow it to use JIT and take advantage of the improved javascript performance.

Comment: Yep...pretty much same as they said. I figured I'd wait for login and try to be rid of that notification, clicking Wait - just pops up quick and way too often. Unless it won't work at all??  Thanks ci